# Joomla Span of blog on custom template

Tags: html, css, templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I have created a custom joomla template. Inside of which I have a `div` with a `span of 12` which takes up the entire screen. Inside of this I have a `div` of `size 9` and of `size 3`. My first article displayed takes up the entire `span of 9` but the proceeding articles only take up 50% of the `span 9`. Using the inspect element function I have determined that the span of the item is in fact a `span of 6` and not `12` the first article. As i have not coded this in my template I don't know how to change this `span from 6 to 12` (as to fill the span 9 completely) 
here is the page that I am referencing 
http://www.alanmccarthy.com/index.php/personall

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this issue. I needed to change the article layout in the options part of the articles section.